# How to integrate JqueryUI Tabs in Blazor webAssembly application

Tags: blazor, jquery-ui-tabs, asp.net-core-5.0

I have created a Blazor(.Net Core 5.0) web application. Now due to some enhanced business requirement, I am in need to integrate JqueryUI with Blazor(.Net Core 5.0) web application.

Somewhere over google, I came across an article where it says that JqueryUI files link reference would go in Index.html(static file). But things did not workout for me.
Can you you please share some sample or any close reference to its implementation.

Comment: You can try to refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65308885/how-to-import-jquery-ui-to-blazor-webassembly).

Comment: Not an answer to your question but if your only looking for tab control there's a great example on the Blazor University without js. https://blazor-university.com/templating-components-with-renderfragements/creating-a-tabcontrol/